# I cannot use passenger for my ruby on rails application on dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, dreamhost

I want to do some programming in ruby on rails on my Dreamhost server, so I connected via ssh and created a small application. Then I started the server and it worked. The problem is, that after some time the server kills itself. So I tried to activate Passenger in the user panel (which also has the advantage, that I don't have to connect to port 3000). Now I could only see the welcome page and every time, I wanted to display another page it gave me a 404 error. 
Now I don't understand, why the app works on the server included in the app, but not on the apache server.

Maybe you can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following the steps at http://railstips.org/2008/12/14/deploying-rails-on-dreamhost-with-passenger?

Comment: Yes, I tried that one, but when I typed "capify .", it said command not found. Should that work without me doing anything or do I have to setup something before I can use it?

Comment: No, you have to set up capistrano.

Comment: Sorry, I finished the guide successfully, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The secret sauce being that you need the gems bin directory on your path. For example, `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`. It's funny that I never see that mentioned anywhere, even in guides that claim to be from-the-scratch.